# How to change component's nodes properties manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

For test purposes, I need to programatically change cursor position in input field (or just simulate selectionStart attribute somehow). I've noticed that when I get the node element I can access its DOM methods like setSelectionRange, setAttribute, etc. However when I do:

```
let component = mount(<Form/>);

expect(component.find('#postbackURL').node.selectionStart).toBe(0); // true
component.find('#postbackURL').node.setSelectionRange(2, 2);
expect(component.find('#postbackURL').node.selectionStart).toBe(2); // false, still 0
```

setSelectionRange is fired, but doesn't have any effect.

Why it doesn't work? Is there any other way I can change `selectionStart` property?